# How to Use Lisence Key Wordpress Theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, ioncube

I have done a lot of searches on search engines but I did not find out how to do that.

I found a way on stackoverflow, but it's not very specific, check the link here. [questions/6611611/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611611/protect-wordpress-theme-with-license-key-validation)

I don't know exactly how to use ionCube as validation and replace my URL as a key validation.

How do I implement ionCube in my wordpress theme so that every use of my template uses the license I made?

UPDATE

[SOLVED]

From [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611611/protect-wordpress-theme-with-license-key-validation)

Comment: It's pretty clear on the thread you linked, what you tried? What went wrong? Note that on the very thread someone argued that WordPress themes should be distributed under GPL license and so the code should be human readable hence not obfuscated..

Comment: I want every user of my template to have a key to activate my template, how do I do that?

Comment: There is this blog article on protecting a Wordpress plugin. Perhaps it will be a useful start. http://blog.ioncube.com/2016/08/23/faq-encoding-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: thanks u answer dear, may question solved from this link update.